# Request not processing using jackson REST web services (RESTful Spring Controllers) @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I got this error when I was working with Jackson REST web services (RESTful Spring Controllers) @PathVariable.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class EmployeeRestControllerImpl{

        @GetMapping("/employeeList/{empId}")
            public @ResponseBody
               ResponseMessage getEmployeeListById(@PathVariable int empId){
    
                   .....
                   System.out.println(employees.get(empId));
                   .....
        }

    }
```

employees:`[{"firstName":"ABC","lastName":"ABC"},{"firstName":"XYZ","lastName":"XYZ"},{"firstName":"DEF","lastName":"DEF"}]`

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'empId' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Is it necessary to change the primitive type to wrapper object.. why? Help me to figure out .Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

- The error is very specific

  > org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'empId' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.

  Seems you are requesting the API without any `empId` hence the null value for path variable. The error message says that if you want to support null then instead of primitive `int` variable user wrapper objects like `Integer`

as

```
@GetMapping("/employeeList/{empId}")
public @ResponseBody ResponseMessage getEmployeeListById(@PathVariable Integer empId)
```

- Try passing right empId in the request `http://localhost:8080/api/employeeList/123` and it should work